# Linking Django with PysimpleGUI

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am really new to both of them. I have created a app with PysimpleGUI that gets the webcam input. So I need to link it to a website that uses Django, so that the webcam input is displayed on a webpage. What I need to know is whether it is possible to connect the two components together and/or are there any alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is pretty vague. Webcam input is a continuous signal. You could make things work with Django, in your case, can play streaming video from webcam input.

However, I suggest you to use other servers such as angular as it deviates from what Django is intended to do.